# How to properly UPDATE mysql data using php inside an If statement?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have been stuck on this problem for a couple hours and what I researched didn't help me either. I am trying to Update my database only when the input matches the name already in the database. How can I fix this code and thank you for your help.

```
         //Input 
      <form>
        <input  type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="name_input" placeholder="Enter Name">
              </div>

        <a href="" name="name_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Enter</a>
        </div> 
      </form>


    //The PHP code 

    $name = "";
    $name_input = "";
    $points = "";

    if(isset($_POST['name_btn'])){

        $name_input = strip_tags($_POST['name_input']);
        $name = $user['name'];
        $points = $user['points'];

    if($name_input == $name) {

        $points = points + 3;

    $upate_data = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET points='$points' WHERE id='4'");

    } 
    }
```

Comment: you should be getting undefined index notices.

Comment: and `href`'s do not work with POST arrays, so your code is failing on more than one level and as to the origin of `$user`.

Comment: @Fred -ii- The database is properly connected to the page and I am able to get other values using $user, I removed the href and it still does not work.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php set to catch and display, and use `mysqli_error($con)` on the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add a method in your form, also href's doesn't work with post, should be like this:

```
//Input 
<form method="post">
    <input  type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
    </div>

    <!-- <a href="" name="name_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Enter</a> -->

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="name_btn">
    </div> 
</form>


//The PHP code 

<?php

$databaseHost = 'localhost';
$databaseName = 'testing';
$databaseUsername = 'root';
$databasePassword = '';

$con = mysqli_connect($databaseHost, $databaseUsername, $databasePassword, $databaseName);

$name = "";
$name_input = "";
$points = "";

if(isset($_POST['name_btn'])){

    echo "aaa";

    $name_input = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $name = $user['name'];
    $points = $user['points'];


echo "&nbsp&nbsp Data updated successfully!";

    if($name_input == $name) {

    $points = points + 3;

    $upate_data = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET points='$points' WHERE id='4'");

    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test if a result exists by using a select query and obtaining count of returned rows. For example;

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE username = '$name_input'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count > 0){
    //the result exists
    $points = points + 3;
    $upate_data = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET points='$points' WHERE id='4'");
}else{
    //result does not exist
}
```

Also i see you get post data of `name` variable here `$name_input = strip_tags($_POST['name']);` yet in the form the input field's name attribute is `name_input` here `<input  type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="name_input" placeholder="Enter Name">` You should check that out.